# Pyinstaller on Mac – Bundled Application crashes but unix executable works fine?

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, pyinstaller, bundles

I'm a Mac user and I used PyInstaller on a Pythonfile named weatherapp.py to get a mac Application Bundle. It's the TKInter GUI form [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D8-snVfekto&t=6s). After the process is complete this is how the inside of the 'dist'-folder looks like:

[image: Application directory]

My Problem is when I launch the weatherapp.app (column on the left) it crashes before it could even open.
But when I run the weatherapp unix executable (column on the right) the GUI opens without any errors.

How do I get the .app to work as well? Thanks for your help

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: no, I gave up 